# How to find an element inside another ContentView?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Inside my MainPage.xaml, I have:

```
<local:MyButton x:Name="btnStart" Text="START" Image="Icon.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="70"></local:MyButton>
```

Here is the code of MyButton.xaml:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="mainContainer">
        <Button x:Name="button" Text="TEMP"></Button>
        <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,15,15,15" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
  </Grid>
```

Now, inside the code behind of MainPage, I would like to do something like:

```
btnStart.button.Click += btnStartClick;
```

So, how can I access "button"?

I already tried this, but returned NULL:

```
btnStart.FindByName<Button>("button").Clicked += btnStartClick;
```

Perharps I need to add the code above in a specific event different than the constructor?

Any other suggestion to help me expose the Click event, would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you should really expose a custom event on your MyButton.  MainPage shouldn't need to know anything about the internals of the MyButton class.

Comment: that's a good point. I'm trying to discover how. A tutorial link would help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option-1

You can expose an event in your custom control.

**Steps:**

1. Declare event in your custom control.

   ```
   public event EventHandler ButtonClickEvent;
   ```
2. Assign Clicked event-handler for button defined in control's XAML

   ```
   <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="mainContainer">
            <Button x:Name="button" Text="TEMP" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
            <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,15,15,15" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
        </Grid>
   ```
3. And invoke your custom event in it (in control's code-behind)

   ```
   void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        ButtonClickEvent?.Invoke(sender, e);
   }
   ```
4. **Usage:** You can now bind the event in parent-page where you use your custom control.

   ```
    <local:MyButton
          ButtonClickEvent="OnButtonClick" />
   ```

### Option-2 (recommended if you are using MVVM)

Expose a command as bindable property (which in turn will be bound to inner button control). You can then bind this custom command to parent-page's ViewModel.

**Sample code**

```
public partial class MyButton : ContentView
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //create binding between parent control and child controls
        btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding(nameof(ClickCommand), source: this));
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ClickCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "ClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyButton),
            defaultValue: null);

    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ClickCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClickCommandProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<local:MyButton
    ClickCommand="{Binding OnTapCommand}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm struggle at calling the Invoke method, because my "ButtonClickEvent" is always NULL. Any clue?

Comment: `ButtonClickEvent` will not be null - if you assign it a event-handler (as described in step 4)

Comment: oh, that was my mistake. I added the event to another button. Awesome! Thanks!